# How do I remove old textBoxs , saving user input data, while adding the new textBoxes onclick?

Tags: javascript

**How do I remove old textBoxs , and save user input, while adding the new textBoxes onclick? I want the user to be able to add a new page, without the old page showing.**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
 var boxCount=1;
 var boxName=0;
 function newBox(){
  var input=document.createElement("input");
   input.type="text"
   input.name="fname_"+boxCount;
   input.placeholder="fname_"+boxCount;
   document.getElementById('box').appendChild(input);
  var new_line=document.createElement("br");document.getElementById('box').appendChild(new_line);
  var new_line2=document.createElement("br");document.getElementById('box').appendChild(new_line2);
     
   boxCount++;
 }
</script>
    <head>
      <body>
  <button type="button" onclick="newBox()">Add Property</button><br/>
  <form action="#" method="post">
   <br/><span id="box"></span><br/><br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: just create a variable which keeps storing the data or better an array

Comment: I am very new to javascript, so could you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set the type of each previous input to **hidden**;
See below:

```js
var input,
    inputCount = 0;

function newInput () {
  if (input !== undefined) {
    input.type = "hidden";  
  }
  inputCount++;
  
  input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "text";
  input.name = input.placeholder = "fname" + inputCount;
  document.getElementById("box").appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="newInput()">Add Property</button><br/>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <br/><span id="box"></span><br/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I hardly think he's gonna use ajax to send his values; Moreover, in the current context, I understand "remove old textBoxs" as "hide them from the user". 
@TC Hakeem, precisions ?

Comment: I may be wrong but I would rather wait for @TC Hakeem 's confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I remove old text boxes, and save user input, while adding the new text boxes on click?

So on click if there is an existing box, save its name and value to an object, then push that object to an array, then remove the box.

Now you can manipulate or iterate the array of objects with ease, and theres no hidden text inputs loading up the dom.

```js
var boxCount=1;
var boxName=0;
var values = [];
function newBox(){
    var box = document.querySelector('.box');
    if(box) {
        values.push({'name': box.name, 'value': box.value});
        box.remove();
    }
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type="text"
    input.className = 'box';
    input.name="fname_"+boxCount;
    input.placeholder="fname_"+boxCount;
    document.getElementById('box').appendChild(input);
    boxCount++;
    console.log(values);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="newBox()">Add Property</button><br/>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <br/><span id="box"></span><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: That is a very clean way of solving this issue may I say. The array will allow easy data manipulation if needed. Just what I was also thinking. :)

Comment: There is a problem with that solution; If the user hits *submit*, only the last input will be send via the form. It requires additional codes to add stored values to the request.

Comment: This answer is what the OP is looking for according to his question.